# Возможно ли отправить файл и параметры?

Tags: php

Возможно ли отправить файл (multipartом) и параметры за один запрос?

Comment: Параметры чего? в смысле данные из формы или что?

Comment: Да, данные формы.

Comment: Да конечно , почему нет https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipart/form-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно нет ограничений .
Типичный пример: страницы отправки электронных писем через webmail со вложенными файлами. При отправке такого письма браузер формирует сообщение типа multipart/form-data, внедряя в него как отдельные части, введённые пользователем, тему, адрес получателя, собственно текст письма, так и вложенные файлы.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipart/form-data

Answer (score 0):

Да :)

```
 <form action="http://domain.ru" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p><input type="text" name="text1" value="text default">
  <p><input type="text" name="text2" value="12345">
  <p><input type="file" name="file1">
  <p><input type="file" name="file2">
  <p><input type="file" name="file3">
  <p><input type="submit">
</form>
```